# How to write an inline include

Tags: c++, include

I know that in Java the following two code samples do the same thing, and I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar in C++.

```
// At the top
import System.out.println;

// In a function
        println(" :) ");
```

and

```
// Directly in a function
        System.out.println(" :) ");
```

For example, in C++ I would like to turn this:

```
#include<time.h>
int main ()
{
    clock_t started;
```

Into something like this:

```
int main ()
{
    (time.h)::clock_t started;
```

Is this possible in C++? If so, could someone please show an example?

Comment: Can someone please add the tags "c++-vs-java" "inline-include" and "how-to" to my post, because I don't have enough reputation to make them. Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this to avoid naming conflicts, then use `#include <ctime>` and `std::clock_t` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The `#include` directive are handled by a separate "entity" called the preprocessor―while it isn't a separate program, it is a different component of your compiler and "runs" before code is compiled, and handles macros, `#pragma`, etc. It has no notion of modules.

Comment: So there's no way to trick the compiler into doing something similar, right?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to "trick the compiler"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No, sorry. Basically, `#include` just puts the content of the file you specify where you use it. There can be at most one preprocessor directive on a given line, and only the preprocessor can deal with files. Unlike Java and C#, the compiler needs all the declarations when compiling, and can't just merely `#include` a file when importing a namespace.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I just want to be able to declare my testing code inline so that once I'm done testing I'll be able to delete all of the junk code without accidently leaving that is in a different place.

Comment: If you really actually want conditionally active code, look at `<assert.h>`, `#if` and so on.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yep an #if would probably work well :) Sweet! Should have though of that LOL

Answer (score 3):

Source file boundaries don't really matter in C++ - the fact that a particular declaration appears in a certain file doesn't have any significance.

You may be looking for [namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Comment: Wow this is really cool! I had no idea namespaces could do this! Thanks :)